# Trying to color tabs on ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am adding an actionbar to a test app I'm writing, and I see questions throughout stackoverflow about this, but nothing that has helped me at all. Based off of this guide:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html

I'm trying to change the select color for tabs that i'm using on my action bar. The default is that faint blue color. Just as a test I did this:

```
<style name="CustomTab" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
</style>
```

That gives me a solid black tab completely, not the selector part. Can someone help better direct me here? I can't seem to find a good example anywhere.

Comment: I think you can set the Theme in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to define a selector xml file then write this code there and replace your code with this

```
item name="android:background">@drawable/yourfilename</item>
```

and the selector xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/picture_selected" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/picture_selected" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/picture_unselected" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Thank you very much! Am I required to use pictures for my drawables though? Can I just define a single color to be used with the existing images so I don't have to re-create them myself with a new color?

Comment: ya, you can use different colors instead of image.